# How to redirect roture with variable in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

How to Redirect to particular route with variable in Laravel

```
return redirect('orderresult')->with('orderlist', $orderDatas);
```

Comment: pass variable as second parameter in route method like: Redirect::route('users', $id));. for more details check my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
return redirect()->route('orderresult')->with('orderlist', $orderDatas);
```

OR

```
return redirect('orderresult')->with('orderlist', $orderDatas);
```

and access the variable from the session as

```
session('orderlist')
```

provided you have a named route `orderresult`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#redirecting-named-routes
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: i got Undefined variable: orderlist error when redirect @linktoahref

Comment: Are you accessing the variable in the blade or controller method?

Comment: controller @linktoahref

Comment: How exactly are you trying to access the variable? Please update your question

Comment: You need to use same variable in your blade fileL like `orderDatas` and pass it from controller like: `return redirect()->route('orderresult')->with('orderDatas', $orderDatas);`

Comment: @HirenGohel The first parameter is the `key` using which the variables are accessed. I'm not aware of *same variable naming*, please share any such links

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post('user/profile', function () {
    // Update the user's profile...

    return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
});
```

"status" will be in session

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to a route with variable do like following:

With in the route as second parameter either as array or single variable:

For single parameter:

```
return Redirect::route('users', $id));
```

For multiple parameters:

```
return Redirect::route('users', array('nick' => $username,'id' => $id));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :

```
return \Redirect::to('orderresult')->with('orderlist', $orderDatas);
```

And in blade file:

```
@if(Session::has('orderlist'))
  <div class="alert-sucess">
    {{ Session::get('orderlist') }}
  </div>
@endif
```

Hope this work for you !!!